# Trouble writing to html from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a question related to php and html.
I am trying to write in a table from a mysql database.

My question is: Why does it write the text "SEMIFINAL 2" before it writes the table, but in the code the table is written before the text "SEMIFINAL 2"?

I could really use some help. Thanks a lot.

P.S. Here is the code

```
    <html>
    <style>
table { 
color: #333;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
width: 640px; 
border-collapse: 
collapse; border-spacing: 0; 
}

td, th { 
border: 1px solid transparent; /* No more visible border */
height: 30px; 
transition: all 0.3s;  /* Simple transition for hover effect */
}

th {
background: #DFDFDF;  /* Darken header a bit */
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
}

td {
background: #FAFAFA;
text-align: center;
}

/* Cells in even rows (2,4,6...) are one color */ 
tr:nth-child(even) td { background: #F1F1F1; }   

/* Cells in odd rows (1,3,5...) are another (excludes header cells)  */ 
tr:nth-child(odd) td { background: #FEFEFE; }  

tr td:hover { background: #666; color: #FFF; } /* Hover cell effect! */
</style>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$username="root"; 
$password=""; 
$db_name="lol"; 
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("lol") or die("Cannot connect to database");

$query="call semi2";
$results = mysql_query($query);
print('<table align=center>');
print ("<tr>");
 echo '<th>First Name</th>';
 echo '<th>Last Name</th>';
 echo '<th>Victories</th>';
echo "</center>";
$nr_val=0;



if($results === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_row($results)){
echo" <tr>\n";

foreach($row as $value){

echo "<td>$value</td>";

$nr_val++;
}
echo"</tr>";
}
$coln=mysql_num_fields($results);
$nr_inreg=$nr_val/$coln; 

echo "<br>";
echo "<center>";
if ($nr_inreg>0) 
echo "SEMIFINAL 2";

else
die ("Can't find any recording....");

echo "</center>";

mysql_close();
?>

  </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried closing the `<table>` tag before you `echo "SEMIFINAL 2";`? It would be good to see a SC of the result too... It doesn't look like you are closing the `<tr>` for the header either. Can you check those?

Comment: Closing the table helped :)) . Thx a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You forgot the closure table tag
- You have a center closure tag that seems misplaced in your table header

Add the closure table tag closing before outputing your text

Comment: That was the problem :)). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Upvotes are the best way to say thx IMO, I added one to his answer ;)